# Earnshaw Theorem Appliation in Electric Dipoles

Tags: electrostatics

My real question is more like: how can electric dipoles exist? How can the positive and negative charge really exist in equilibrium at the exact same distance from each other?

Comment: 1 Quantum mechanics, 2 dynamic equilibrium . . . https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471288/earnshaws-theorem-in-chemical-bonds/471301#471301